# Make timer ring when finished in background

Tags: java, android-studio, timer, background

I am making a Timer app on android studio that can edit minutes and start down counting and ring when finished and stop ringing when pressing a button but the ringing is not working if I close the app and leave it in background only the timer working. How to let it ring when timer finished in background also.

```
package com.example.timer2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText mEditTextInput;
    private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
    private Button mButtonSet;
    private Button mButtonStartPause;
    private Button mButtonReset;
    private Button fine;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    private boolean mTimerRunning;
    private long mStartTimeInMillis;
    private long mTimeLeftInMillis;
    private long mEndTime;
    public Ringtone r;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE));


        fine =findViewById(R.id.fine);
fine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pauseTimer();
        resetTimer();
        startTimer();
        r.stop();
    }
});
        mEditTextInput = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_input);
        mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);

        mButtonSet = findViewById(R.id.button_set);
        mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause);
        mButtonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);

        mButtonSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String input = mEditTextInput.getText().toString();
                if (input.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Field can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                long millisInput = Long.parseLong(input) * 60000;
                if (millisInput == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a positive number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                setTime(millisInput);
                mEditTextInput.setText("");
            }
        });

        mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTimerRunning) {
                    pauseTimer();
                } else {
                    startTimer();
                }
            }
        });

        mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetTimer();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setTime(long milliseconds) {
        mStartTimeInMillis = milliseconds;
        resetTimer();
        closeKeyboard();
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis;

        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimerRunning = false;
                updateWatchInterface();
                r.play();


            }
        }.start();

        mTimerRunning = true;
        updateWatchInterface();
    }

    private void pauseTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mTimerRunning = false;
        updateWatchInterface();
    }

    private void resetTimer() {
        mTimeLeftInMillis = mStartTimeInMillis;
        updateCountDownText();
        updateWatchInterface();
    }

    private void updateCountDownText() {
        int hours = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 3600;
        int minutes = (int) ((mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 3600) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

        String timeLeftFormatted;
        if (hours > 0) {
            timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                    "%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
        } else {
            timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                    "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
        }

        mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }

    private void updateWatchInterface() {
        if (mTimerRunning) {
            mEditTextInput.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mButtonSet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Pause");
        } else {
            mEditTextInput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mButtonSet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");

            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 1000) {
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < mStartTimeInMillis) {
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void closeKeyboard() {
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putLong("startTimeInMillis", mStartTimeInMillis);
        editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
        editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
        editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);

        editor.apply();

        if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
            mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

        mStartTimeInMillis = prefs.getLong("startTimeInMillis", 600000);
        mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", mStartTimeInMillis);
        mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false);

        updateCountDownText();
        updateWatchInterface();

        if (mTimerRunning) {
            mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0);
            mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 0) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = 0;
                mTimerRunning = false;
                updateCountDownText();
                updateWatchInterface();
            } else {
                startTimer();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

and the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="51dp"
        android:text="     Press I AM Okay to Reset Timer ..."
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/edit_text_input"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
        android:text="I Am Okay  "
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/edit_text_input"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_input"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/text_view_countdown"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="Minutes"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_set"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edit_text_input"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/edit_text_input"
        android:text="Set"
        android:backgroundTint="#2196F3"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_countdown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="60sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_start_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_countdown"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="start"
        android:backgroundTint="#2196F3"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_countdown"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_start_pause"
        android:text="reset"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:backgroundTint="#2196F3"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can make a "if" Statement that looks if your time hits 0.

There are multiple aproaches. you can even let the timer count up and the
"if" statement calls the ringing funtion "if(timer == userinput)".

It all depends on your code we just need to see it, because we don't know what your cooking.

Comment: yes of course i published my code